# Accessing Production API URL for jXchange Rest Legacy

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

Our institution is unable to get a response from jx-rl-proxy-jxapp.prod.ipaas.jha-sys.com. We are able to create an Oauth token with the https://ims.jhacloudservices.com token url. Our local Ip has been whitelisted but the url is not available.

Currently we are using Insomnia and Postman for testing with unsuccessful response from the jx-rl-proxy-jxapp.prod.ipaas.jha-sys.com url. We cannot ping successfully the jx-rl-proxy-jxapp.prod.ipaas.jha-sys.com url.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the IP whitelisting, make sure there is no proxy interfering with the traffic to the endpoint.